# Can I execute multiple statements with shorthand if && in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, shorthand

```javascript
var foo = true;

function doThis() {alert("do this");}
function doThat() {alert("do that");}

// fine
if(foo) {
    doThis();
    doThat();
}

// fine
foo && (doThis());

// NO, syntax error
foo && (doThis(); doThat(););
```

Is this even possible? Or I should'v not done this at all?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, if you separate the functions with commas:

```
foo && (bar(), baz())
```

This is a *terrible* coding practice, but it's useful for minifying code, or the purposes of [code golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com).

```
if (foo) {
    bar();
    baz();
}
```

turns into:

```
foo&&(bar(),baz())
```

and

```
if (!foo) {
    bar();
    baz();
}
```

turns into:

```
foo||(bar(),baz())
```

and

```
if (foo) {
    bar();
    baz();
} else {
    fizz();
    buzz();
}
```

turns into:

```
foo?(bar(),baz()):(fizz(),buzz())
```

although the variables would likely be renamed in a minifier to something like:

```
a&&(b(),c())
```

Comment: That's what I'm looking for, and thanks for the heads up. I was just wondering if it's possible.

Comment: Why is that terrible coding practice? It is a strange syntax but once you get the hold of it, it is fine I guess!

Comment: @GreenCode It's fine until someone else has to read and understand that code.

Comment: @GreenCode, it's terrible because it's not readable, and not easily understandable by most developers. It's too terse to be particularly useful, and opens up the possibility for developers to make foolish mistakes that the more verbose syntax would not allow.

Comment: well what you know everything  i learned in last 3 hours is in one place.. :DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD

Comment: i think it's not good for defining whole lot of logic, but for quick assigning that you don't want to be distraction for future. this is goood.

Comment: check out the code i've written using this new information. http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/j7Ynt/3/
i was trying to make nodejs certain functions work in sync, `C`, so C only is ran when A and B both are done. Without using any modules. While i also happen to write smaller log function that makes my life easy by not writing console.log(etc every freaking time. i just write `log='hey';` and its printed like magic. :D

Comment: It's not terrible coding practice if you work alone and are coding something personal that is not meant to be seen in the cloud or by other devs. If the developer understands it himself, it should be fine. My opinion anyway, thank you @zzzzBov for the shorthand tricks!

Answer (score 2):

You can't put a semicolon in the middle of an expression.

```
foo && (doThis() || doThat());
```

As `doThis` has no return value, it evaluates as follows:

```
true && (doThis() || doThat());
(doThis() || doThat());
(undefined || doThat());
(doThat());
undefined;
```

But as answered by @zzzzBov, the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) can also be used and it is better in the sense that it doesn't depend on return values.

Note that such shorthands are not very readable, you should let minification tools do that kind of work. (e.g. [Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home))

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator):

```
foo && (doThis(), doThat());
```

Of course if `doThis` returns a `truthy` value you can also have:

```
foo && doThis() && doThat();
```

But it's more like;

```
if (foo)
    if (doThis())
        doThat();
```

However usually this "shorthand" are not used if there is no assignment on the left, because makes the code uglier and less readable.